# Author first name abbreviation shows up in citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apacite

I am using the following packages for citation support:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}% Citation support
```

Inside my thesis, I am citing the authors as:

```
\citet{belkin1992information}
\citet{brooks1983using}
```

[image: the last name of the author with the first name abbreviated]

[image: the last name of the author only]

The BibTeX entries are as follows:

```
@article{belkin1992information,
  title={Information filtering and information retrieval: Two sides of the same coin?},
  author={Belkin, Nicholas J and Croft, W Bruce},
  journal={Communications of the ACM},
  volume={35},
  number={12},
  pages={29--38},
  year={1992},
  publisher={ACM}
}

@inproceedings{brooks1983using,
  title={Using discourse analysis for the design of information retrieval interaction mechanisms},
  author={Brooks, Helen M and Belkin, Nicholas J},
  booktitle={ACM SIGIR Forum},
  volume={17},
  number={4},
  pages={31--47},
  year={1983},
  organization={ACM}
}
```

I prefer how the second paper is being cited and would like to have a consistent format for citation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I get "Belkin and Croft (1992) Brooks and Belkin (1983)" when I turn the code shown in the question so far into a fully working example document: https://gist.github.com/moewew/6a4685b6051112a08ea00a93012b433d. It is my understanding that APA style (6th ed., which is what `apacite` implements) requires initials be added to author's names if their last name is not enough to identify them uniquely (because there is a different author with the same last name). IIRC that only applies to the first author, though. So what you are seeing is exactly in line with APA requirements ...

Comment: ... *if* you cite another entry (which is not shown in your question) written by a `Belkin` other than `Belkin, Nicholas J`.

Comment: Not that it is likely to help here, but I usually recommend to end initials with `.`s in the `.bib` database. So instead of `author={Brooks, Helen M and Belkin, Nicholas J},` I'd write `author={Brooks, Helen M. and Belkin, Nicholas J.},` that way BIbTeX doesn't think the second name of `Brooks, Helen M` is `M`.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. Most of them had Belkin, Nicholas J while one had Belkin, Nicholas in its BibTeX